# Windows PC sends ARP requests to outside subnet

Tags: dhcp, arp

I have a strange behaviour. I am seeing arp requests to another subnet. We have a central DHCP at ....0.2.21. The Client has an adress assigned from it ....1.1.20, with a 24 bit netmask. The Client sends ARP requests to the DHCP-Server IP outside its own subnet. This should not happen at all.
Any ideas? Anyone sees that behaviour? (For what i can tell, all our Windows clients do that) Is this a general bug in Windows DHCP-Client/Arp or do i have a configuration issue?

The structure is: [Client] - [Firewall] - [Router] - [DHCP-Server]

I first tried it in another stackexchange, but got sent here. The original post has a screenshot from a wireshark capture in it. (Not allowed to post images yet.)
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79899/windows-pc-sends-arp-requests-to-outside-subnet

Comment: Is the DHCP server at least physically on the same ethernet, or are you using DHCP relay? Is the default gateway also out-of-subnet?

Comment: There is a DHCP-Relay configured on the firewall which redirects the DHCP request to the DHCP-Server behind another Router.